# Add a hibernate result object to a Array list

Tags: java, hibernate, loops, dao

Is the syntax right for the following:

```java
    List<CEntity> ctxts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (NEntity number : numbers) {
            ctxts.add(contDao.findByNumber("123456"));
        }

    Map<String, List<CEntity>> cotextsMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (CEntity cotxt : ctxts) {
            cotextsMap.get('test').add(cotxt);
        }
```

I want to loop on each number I have in the numbers list and execute a hibernate custom query using `@Query` annotation.

update i am getting this error in compilation:

```
 method java.util.List.add(com.data.model.CEntity) is not applicable
        (actual argument java.util.List<com.data.model.CEntity> cannot be converted to com.data.model.CEntity by method invocation conversion)
        [ERROR] method java.util.Collection.add(com.data.model.CEntity) is not applicable
```

Comment: better you can go for findAllByNumber( String num)

Comment: it is not my goal to query findallby.

Comment: i want to know whether the java syntax is right. Especially the first 4 lines of code.

Comment: ohk got it , did u get any exception/error?

Comment: yes, i am getting add CEntity in list cannot be applied.

Comment: post the log trace here. one line comment will not help someone to understand.

Comment: @priyranjan , i updated the question with the error.

Comment: and this is the error i am getting at runtime:  java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to CEntity

Answer (score 0):

1st thing is:
(actual argument java.util.List<com.data.model.CEntity> cannot be converted to com.data.model.CEntity by method invocation conversion)
[ERROR] method java.util.Collection.add(com.data.model.CEntity) is not applicable

 This error mean you are trying to add a list to your ctxts.

1st solution if you sure your element is only return one result:

```
// You may do length ckeck or null check before add to prevent runtime error
ctxts.add(contDao.findByNumber("123456").get(0));
```

OR 
if your return value may have contains multiple results:

```
// You may do length ckeck or null check before add to prevent runtime error
ctxts.addAll(contDao.findByNumber("123456"));
```

For more details about how to use List and ArrayList you can refer to [Java.util.list documentatation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)